# Calculate Azure Function latency , if multiple instances of functions are running

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-log-analytics, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I have created Azure Function which is Azure Cosmos DB Change feed triggered and this is deployed under SKU Consumption plan.

Syncing millions of records from one cosmos to another using the function that we have created.

I was able to calculate the time taken for the function for processing the items for single instance of running azure function. But we are looking for if there is any way we could calculate time taken by azure function to process 1 million records in case of scale out ( multiple instances of azure function running).

Answer (score 0):

The Monitor Blade for a function in the Azure Portal runs the following query.

```
requests
| project
    timestamp,
    id,
    operation_Name,
    success,
    resultCode,
    duration,
    operation_Id,
    cloud_RoleName,
    invocationId=customDimensions['InvocationId']
| where timestamp > ago(30d)
| where cloud_RoleName =~ '{function_app_name}' and operation_Name =~ '{function_name}'
| order by timestamp desc
| take 20
```

You should be able to use the same as long as the [sampling percentage set into the `host.json` file is `100`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#applicationinsightssamplingsettings) to ensure all invocations are logged.

You can get the query for your function from the Azure Portal like so

[image: invocation-query-from-azure-portal]